# CheckBox within an AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

I have a following piece of code

```
   public void showAlert(final Context context) {

    mContext = context;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( 
    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_layout,null);
    builder.setView(view);
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

    try {

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
                new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
                      boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "CheckBox is 
                          CHecked");
                        } else {
                            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "CheckBox is 
                         Not Checked");
                        }
                        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Inside ChecBox 
                       CheckedListner");
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("TAG","Exception-->"+e);
    }


    builder.setPositiveButton(PositiveButton, new 
   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

       //some code here:

       }
       });

    builder.setNegativeButton(NegativeButton, new 
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    alert.show();
   }
```

Whenever someone press the CheckBox it closes the Alert Dialog, which i dont want.
Actually when user click the checkbox i have some data which will be passed to a another listener(an Interface) but my dialog is getting closed when checkbox is clicked.

Can anybody tell me how to keep the alertdialog intact even if somebody click the checkbox.

Comment: use **builder.setCancelable(false);**

Answer (score 0):

Use below method while creating alert dialog.

```
 builder.setCancelable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`.
2. Remove `alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT)`

**Try this:**

```
.....
...........

final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your code just copy and paste

```
public void showAlert(final Context context) {

    mContext = context;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( 
    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_layout,null);
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

    try {

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
                new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
                      boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "CheckBox is 
                          CHecked");
                        } else {
                            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "CheckBox is 
                         Not Checked");
                        }
                        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Inside ChecBox 
                       CheckedListner");
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("TAG","Exception-->"+e);
    }


    builder.setPositiveButton(PositiveButton, new 
   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

       //some code here:

       }
       });

    builder.setNegativeButton(NegativeButton, new 
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    alert.show();
   }
```